# EditText.setMaxLines() programmatically not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to set Maxline for EditText programmatic, It's not giving extra space on EditText after clearing Text.
If I set maxLine in xml the extra space is visible even there is no text in EditText.

How to give these extra space by programmatic way instead of using xml. because I need to use same xml for many Views.

**Programmatic code**

```
public void showDescriptionDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_upload_description);
    final EditText edtDescription = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edt_upload_description);
    edtDescription.setHint(context.getString(R.string.description));
    edtDescription.setSingleLine(false);
    edtDescription.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION);
    edtDescription.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
    edtDescription.setMaxLines(5);
    edtDescription.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    edtDescription.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());
    edtDescription.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_INSET);
    if (description != null) {
        edtDescription.setText(description);
    }
    dialog.show();


    dialog.findViewById(R.id.img_upload_description_back).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.findViewById(R.id.img_upload_description_done).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            description = edtDescription.getText().toString();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_upload_description_done).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            description = edtDescription.getText().toString();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

**XML Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_upload_description_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/upload"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back_white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="@string/title_description"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_large" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_upload_description_done"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/done"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_tick_white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_upload_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:hint="@string/txt_upload_description_hint"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:minLines="5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_upload_description_done"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@color/btn_magenta"
        android:text="@string/txt_done"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


</LinearLayout>
```

If I use *android:minLines="5"* in EditText then only extra space appears in EditText even there is no text

**Problem Screenshot**
[image: Problem Images]

**Expected Result Screenshot**
[image: Expected Result]

Comment: after setting `maxLines()` programatically, call your `edittext.invalidate();`

Comment: try using `setLines(5)` instead of `setMaxLines(5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set android:inputType="text" in your xml and remove android:minLines = "5".

Answer (score 7):

You can make your editext responsive my using the following code in your

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and remove

```
  android:minLines="5"
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove line `edtDescription.setSingleLine(false);` from your code. It should works. Look for detail of answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11409015/5241603).